# How do disable control by iPhone headphones?

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

I have bought 2 iPhone headphones from Amazon, good quality earphones with 5-star reviews, but unfortunately there seem an issue where it randomly initiates commands.

Music forwards, music rewards, Siri asks me if I have a question, all features that would be normally initiated by pressing your headphone buttons.

So the headphone mostly make listening music on the iPhone impossible, because of all the random control features being initiated.

How can I disable these headphone controls? The quality of the audio is pretty good and I'd like to keep using these headphones.

Answer (score 5):

This is trivially accomplished by removing the third pin from the connectivity. You could buy an adapter for this purpose if you don't want to change headsets or get what appears to be a faulty switch in it repaired.

- [http://www.amazon.com/EZOPower-Headset-Adapter-Smartphone-smartphone/dp/B0046FMRGA/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0046FMRGA)

Basically the green plug goes into your phone and the headphones go to the black end of the cable.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have found the easier and best fix for this problem.

I had the same issue with a new pair of Sony headphones and spent hours researching online to try and find how to stop the inline controls from randomly start/stopping my music, and by setting off Siri.

Heres the super easy fix....

Take the lightening to 3.5mm adaptor that came with your iPhone.
Look carefully into the 3.5mm plug end and you will see that there are 4 small silver dimples inside the white plastic hole.
The first silver dimple is set about 1mm into the hole and easy to get it.
This is the one which sends the signal from the headphones back to the iPhone.
Simply cut up a tiny piece of sellotape into a strip about 2mm wide and about 20mm long. 
Poke the long thin end into the hole se that it covers the top of the dimple.
Don't push the strip of sellotape in too far otherwise you could block a different connector as well.
Wrap the end of the sellotape that sticks out, over the top of the connector which means that you can grab it and remove in the future if you ever need to.
Now push your headphones into the socket which will push the sellotape against the silver dimple and the sellotape prevents the signal getting though.

Voila the inline controls no longer work!!

Enjoy

Antony

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable controls...you can just return headphones to Amazon

Comment: There are lots of ways to bypass a flakey switch. I agree returning defective merch is good in general, but it doesn't explain how things work since not all people with this issue will be in a return window or find it economical to get headphones repaired.

Comment: He can't disable controls by software, he should disable third pin buying another accessory wich means more expenses and more things in the pocket...is non-sense considering that defective products are replaced for free from Amazon...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of risking damaging your phone or earbuds any further, I have a simple and easy way to fix this. So simply take some scotch tape and a knife of some sort and cut it to the length of the first metal band on the headphone jack:

[image]

So in this case it would be the Microphone band. Simply wrap the tape around it, make sure that you only use 1 layer as putting to much on can stop the jack from entering the phone.

From there just put it in your phone (depending on what tape you use it may seem like it didnt actually go in but just test it out and see if it works)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but I fixed it by plugging in a different pair, to confuse your phone, then switch back. Just borrow a friend's headphones for a sec to do that. Hope it works for you. I just found this out on accident a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, I use an aux extension cable. It disables all input from the headphone buttons. The one is have is really long, so it's a little inconvenient, but I'm sure you can find a short one.