# How to disable inline volume controls on headphones connected to mac?

Tags: audio, headphones, kernel-extensions

The inline volume up button on my Apple headphones randomly engages sometimes, which raises my mid-2013 Macbook Air's volume to the max. This is bad for my hearing and can be quite startling. Is there a way to disable the volume controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I wanted to answer [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181887/how-do-disable-control-by-iphone-headphones), but I didn't have enough reputation.)

*Please note that [loading and unloading](https://osxdaily.com/2015/06/24/load-unload-kernel-extensions-mac-os-x/) [kernel extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Extend/Extend.html) can have unintended consequences. This solution worked for me without causing any issues on my mid-2013 Macbook Air, but that may not be the case for your setup. Understand what you're doing and perform at your own risk.*

1. Open Terminal
2. With headphones plugged in, enter this command to ensure that `AppleMikeyHIDDriver` is controlling your headphones `hidutil list | grep AppleMikeyHIDDriver`. **DO NOT CONTINUE IF THE OUTPUT IS BLANK.** My output looked like this:

```
0x0      0x0       0x0        12        1     0x100000975 (null)    AppleMikeyHIDDriver Apple Mikey HID Driver             (null)    (null)
```

3. Run this command to ensure that the `com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver` kernel extension is running `kextstat | grep com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver`. **DO NOT CONTINUE IF THE OUTPUT IS BLANK.** My output looked like this:

```
179    0 0xffffff7f83cf9000 0x2000     0x2000     com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver (131) DE4003F6-F4F3-3C84-AB83-6CCDE6CF5DFC <49 8 5 3 1>
```

4. Unplug your headphones from your mac. The next step failed for me if they were plugged in with the following error:

```
(kernel) Can't remove kext com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver; services failed to terminate - 0xe00002c7.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver - (iokit/common) unsupported function.
```

5. Run this command to disable the inline volume and mic control `sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver`. You may need to enter your password.

If you ever want to enable it in the future just run `sudo kextload -b com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver` or reboot your mac and everything should go back to normal.

Comment: What to do if output is blank?